# Animating the motion of a particle in 3D in Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have 3xN array  positions that vary in time for a particle. I want to take the coordinates at each time point, plot that position as a point on a 3D axis and then repeat, creating an animation.

I can create a single image of this effect using matplotlib's Axes3D

```
x_a = particle_a[:,0]
y_a = particle_a[:,1]
z_a = particle_a[:,2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax.scatter(x_a, y_a, z_a, c='b')
plt.show
```

'particle_a' is just an array of shape (N,3) where N is the number of timepoints.

How can I animate this?

Comment: Have you tried playing around and extending any of the [matplotlib animation examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/index.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting [this example from the matplotlib site](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html) you can represent a particle moving in 3D with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def make_helix(n):
    theta_max = 8 * np.pi
    theta = np.linspace(0, theta_max, n)
    x, y, z = theta, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)
    helix = np.vstack((x, y, z))

    return helix

def update_lines(num, dataLines, lines) :
    for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines) :
        line.set_data(data[0:2, num-1:num])
        line.set_3d_properties(data[2,num-1:num])
    return lines

# Attach 3D axis to the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

n = 100
data = [make_helix(n)]

lines = [ax.plot(data[0][0,0:1], data[0][1,0:1], data[0][2,0:1], 'o')[0]]

# Setthe axes properties
ax.set_xlim3d([0.0, 8*np.pi])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-1.0, 1.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([-1.0, 1.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.set_title('3D Test')

# Creating the Animation object
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_lines, n, fargs=(data, lines),
                              interval=50, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

(replace `helix` with your own data and set the axes limits accordingly).